# How to use notifyItemRangeChanged with RecyclerView.ItemAnimator for custom animation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

Let's suppose I have [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) and contains 50 items and let's suppose again I made some changes on these items `(4, 5, 6)` so I'll use this command to update items that I changed `galleryAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(4, 3);`, I want when using that command, Hide the target items for 3 seconds (fade-out animation) and after that show again (fade-in animation).

How can I do that using [RecyclerView.ItemAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator)?